# JComboBox getSelectedIndex () always returns 0 or -1

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I run into a problem with my code and I can't solve it.

What I am trying to do is fill the jComboBox with MySQL data and then get the index of the selected item so that I can use it for other activities. I am completing jComboBox using array list or array

And here is the code for the array or array list:

```
public ArrayList<User> listarUser() {
User us;
ArrayList listaUser = new ArrayList();
Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
Connection con = conexion.getConnction();
Statement st;
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet rs;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM user u INNER JOIN nivel n ON u.idNivel=n.idNivel ORDER BY user";
try {
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = (com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet) st.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
        us = new User();
        us.setUser(rs.getString("user"));
        us.setPass(rs.getString("pass"));
        us.setNumEmpleado(rs.getString("numEmpleado"));
        us.setIdNivel(rs.getInt("IdNivel"));
        us.setNombreNivel(rs.getString("nivel"));
        listaUser.add(us);
        
    }
    con.close();
    rs.close();
    st.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alerta (Usuario), contacte con un administrador de sistema\n Error:" + e);
}
return listaUser;
```

}

Here is my code to complete jComboBox:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {                
int i = us.tblUser.getSelectedRow();
if (i > -1) {
    Catalogo cat = new Catalogo();
    ArrayList<Catalogo> cata = cat.listarCatalogo(Sesiones.tablaCatalogoIndependiente);
    for (Catalogo catalogo : cata) {
        Catalogo c = new Catalogo(catalogo.getIdCatalogo(), nombre);
        us.cbxAutonomo.getModel().setSelectedItem(c);
    }
    Catalogo catt = (Catalogo) this.us.cbxAutonomo.getSelectedItem();
    int indice = this.us.cbxAutonomo.getSelectedIndex();
    String indice2 = us.cbxAutonomo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String texto = "psosicion " + indice + " id de la lista " + indice2;
    System.err.println(texto);
```

}

The result:

```
psosicion -1 id de la lista Administrativo
```

Comment: Won't solve your problem but you should be using an ActionListener (not a MouseListener) to listen for the selection of  an item in the combo box. The issue is with the structure of your code. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for a working example that shows how to structure the code so the listener and combo box are in the same class so you know the listener is referencing the combo box that has been added to the frame.  We have no idea what the "us" variable references.

Comment: click on JTABLE has MouseListener event, I don't use button

Comment: Then what does a combo box have to do with the table? As I stated in my answer if you have a reference to the combo box that is displayed on the frame then the code should work. It if doesn't work, then you don't have a reference to the combo box. There is nothing we can do to help, because the issue is the structural design of your classes.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at the end of the code.